# add others value to select option

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to make option value with others , which if the user need to write other values input text will being shows to him to add what he want , otherwise he can add from the option select box , I have an issue with that which it add only the input field and not adding the value from the optin box , Can any one help me with that the project is with laravel framework
here's my form :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 unit">
        <label class="label float-ar">من فضلك اختر هوايات الطفل</label>
        <div class="select " id="admDivChecktop">
            <select name="childHoppy" class="col-md-12 sel-has-p"  id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
                <option value="none" selected disabled>اختر هوايات الطفل</option>
                <option value="القرأه">القراه</option>
                <option value="الرياضة">الرياضة </option>
                <option value="السباحه">السباحه</option>
                <option value="الرسم">الرسم </option>

                <option id="admOption" value="0">others</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-md-12 unit" >
        <label class="label">أَضف بيانات أخري لهواية طفلك</label>
        <div class="input"  >
            <input type="text"  class="col-md-12 bg-hover" name="childHoppy" >

            <label class="icon-left" >
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
{
    if(nameSelect){
        admOptionValue = document.getElementById("getFname").value;
        alert(admOptionValue);
        if(admOptionValue == 0){
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "";
             document.getElementById("admDivChecktop").style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: please share the code of `admSelectCheck`

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: `<option value='some unique id'>Display Text Goes Here</option>`

Comment: i dont get the problem. the correct value gets alerted on change. what is the expected output?

Comment: I mean the problem is with saving the value of others or the above that , it's save only the input type field value not the select option

Comment: The script is working fine , but the issue is how can i save the selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add another `hidden` input and store the value there.

If your select has changed, catch the `change` with javascript and update `hidden`'s value. Same for the text input.

What do you think about this?

Pseudo code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="childHoppy" id="childHoppy">

<select name="select" id="select">
  <option>...</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="text" id="text">

<script>
  $document.on('change', '#select, #text', function() {
      $('#childHoppy').val($this.val());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice Idea , i have solved it by putting the value of the last option selection at the first one , so at the both selection option it will put it's last true value